# OSX - How to prevent / remove FDESetup defer that has been set

Tags: macbook, osx-yosemite, filevault

Yesterday I was at a customers and used their WiFi to get an internet connection during a meeting to demonstrate the solution developed so far.

This morning when I try to logo onto my Mac Book Pro I get a "You must enable FileVault" message and when I press cancel, I'm just kicked back to login.

So I logged in as Admin and in a terminal window did

```
fdesetup status
```

and got the following

```
FileVault if Off.
Deferred enablement appear to be active for user 'steve'.
```

So after a quick read of the help and it said that you can us disable to remove the defer so i quickly typed the following and entered the admin password.

```
sudo fdesetup disable -user steve
```

but on checking again with status I get the same message

```
FileVault if Off.
Deferred enablement appear to be active for user 'steve'.
```

I also tried quoting the user name, but that also had no effect.

Right now I can't really get back onto my machine, other than as admin. I don't want to have to sit and wait why it does the encryption, I'd rather get on with things, and I just want to undo what the customers admin team seems to have applied during my meeting yesterday.

If I try to remove the user from fdesetup

```
fdesetup remove -user steve
```

I get the following messsage

```
unable to remove user with the uuid 'CC409971A-BLAH-BLAH-BLAH-BLAHBLAHBLAH".
```

How do I turn off this deferred fdesetup for that user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full restart of the machine seems to apply the 'disable' regardless of what the status request actually reports.

When the machine restarted and I logged in the pop-up was removed and I was able to access my desktop and files.